# Cannot get page information from the server

Tags: php, frontend, backend, ezpublish

My admin page have a error when I try to edit in europe_es region. EZ show me a error about “cannot get page information from the server”.
[image: Error]

Somebody edited a block section in my page, later, this error will show it when I tried edit.

I deleted al block but that error persist.

followed /var/error.log but doesn’t showed anything.

The father is a landing Page
[image: landing page]

Inside this, it has 2 block’s
[image: block's]

“Zona de Prensa” has 2 block with changes

[image: zona]

Please, I need Help,

Comment: Please, post some code, show exactly what you tried to do and how to fix. Your question is too general.

Comment: Hi,
I have new ones news,

I did download code and database of my PRO environment to my Dev environment, but I didnt find any errors.

How is this possible?

Pro environment is corrupted?

Its the same code and database but in pro environment failed and in dev environtment dont failed.

What can I do?

Please, I need your help